# information about the data parameter in layout.prop

Tags: scripting

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop), the `bpy.types.Panel.layout.prop(...)` is defined as:

[image: documentation]
, the data parameter is of type `AnyType`, and if we head to the This `AnyType` documentation page:
It says that the class is an:

```
RNA type used for pointers to any possible data
```

I am confused what this line really means. 
Because, I'm really just experimenting around with the api, since not much concrete resources are available. And, I passed the type: `bpy.types.PoseBone` to make a rig control UI with:

```
bpy.types.Panel.layout.prop(bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones['head'],...)
```

Is `AnyType` more like a generic type, and what are the possible 'types' that could be passed as the `data` parameter?

Comment: For example sake for the `AnyType` object being the active  `PoseBone` type instance `bpy.context.active_pose_bone` which has a "scale" property use `layout.prop(context.active_pose_bone, "scale")`   ... pretty much any blender object that has properties can be used as "data".

Comment: @batFINGER, is this data equal to bpy.data?

Comment: No It can be any blender object eg `layout.prop(bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"], "count")` if you have an array modifier named array on context object.  Or `layout.prop(bpy.data, "is_dirty")` or.... Turn on developer extras in _`Prefs > Interface > display`_ right click on any UI element and "view source" .. will give countless examples of the "any type" nature here.